# I want to add elements to an array - as the user inputs integers

Tags: c#, arrays, dynamic-arrays

Simply put - I'm starting out in C# and I'm trying to make a game right now (text based) where the computer generates a number between 20-30. Then the user takes a number from 1-3 away, then the computer takes a number between 1-3 away and the last person to take a number away to make 0 loses.

My question is - I want to setup an array for user answers, but I cannot figure out how to add an element to the array based on how many rounds it takes the user to finish the game. E.g. They could put in 1 a bunch of times and take their time - adding a lot of elements to the array, or they could do a bunch of 3s and make the game quick.

```
{
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Random rnd = new Random();
        int randomStart = 0;
        randomStart = rnd.Next(20, 30);

        Console.WriteLine("The starting number is {0}", randomStart);
        Console.ReadLine();



    }
}
```

}

I've tried experimenting with array placement and ideas but I left them out of the code that I've put here because it may be easier for you to guide me by just adding to it.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Why stick to an array, why not use a list? Not that I understand why you need to keep those moves for your game...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't change the dimensions of an array dynamically in C#. If you need to add values at run time you to use a different list type.

You might consider a standard List (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19(v=vs.110).aspx) or an ArrayList (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.arraylist(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: Thanks for the reply - I'll look into that.

Comment: Okay - since this is a simple program that doesn't need to be amazing and just needs to work. I had the idea to set userNumber[0] to whatever they put in, then overwrite that element everytime they enter a number. It's not professional but it works :P

Answer (score 0):

Use the List instead of Array..

Visit http://csharp.net-informations.com/collection/list.htm